# Log4j2 - AsyncLoggerConfig.WaitStrategy

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have set the JVM env variable as ***AsyncLoggerConfig.WaitStrategy=Sleep***(even though it is default)

But while starting the server,i am getting null in server log and log4j2 uses disruptor event handler as **BlockingWaitStrategy** instead of **SleepWaitStrategy**

Kindly help

```
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfigHelper creating new disruptor. Ref count is 1.
DEBUG property AsyncLoggerConfig.WaitStrategy=null
DEBUG disruptor event handler uses BlockingWaitStrategy
DEBUG Starting AsyncLoggerConfig disruptor with ringbuffer size=262144, waitStrategy=BlockingWaitStrategy, exceptionHandler=null...
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfig[] starting...
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfigHelper not starting new disruptor, using existing object. Ref count is 2.
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfig[] starting...
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfigHelper not starting new disruptor, using existing object. Ref count is 3.
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfig[] starting...
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfigHelper not starting new disruptor, using existing object. Ref count is 4.
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfig[] starting...
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfigHelper not starting new disruptor, using existing object. Ref count is 5.
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfig[] starting...
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfigHelper not starting new disruptor, using existing object. Ref count is 6.
TRACE AsyncLoggerConfig[] starting...
```

Answer (score 1):

**After adding AsyncLoggerConfig.WaitStrategy=Sleep in System property,i notice wait strategy is changed to Sleep in the log**

> property AsyncLoggerConfig.WaitStrategy=Sleep Starting
>   AsyncLoggerConfig disruptor with ringbuffer size=262144,
>   waitStrategy=SleepingWaitStrategy, exceptionHandler=null...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The web site documentation was outdated. The default was Blocking. The documentation will be [fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1212) to correctly say Blocking in log4j 2.6.

Update: from 2.6, the default will be Timeout, which is like Blocking, but with an occasional wake-up.